# API URL suffix in API Management ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am not finding where to specify or set "API URL suffix" in an Azure APIM ARM Template.  Need to set this field:

[image]

Here is part of the JSON.  Is there a property I can use?

```
 "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
        "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('apimName'), '/', parameters('apiName'))]",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Test Rating APIs",
            "displayName": "Test Rating",
            "serviceUrl": "[parameters('backEndServiceUrl')]",
            "path": "[parameters('backEndServiceUrlPath')]",
            "protocols": [
                "https"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property of [`path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/apis#apicreateorupdateproperties-object) is related to API URL Suffix.

> Relative URL uniquely identifying this API and all of its resource paths within the API Management service instance. It is appended to the API endpoint base URL specified during the service instance creation to form a public URL for this API.

When I set `helloworld` as `Api url suffix`, then in ARM template, it shows in `path`.

[image]

[image]